# CI Pass Variables from Helper to View

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, helper

I have created a Helper file to load common modules on pages. The idea of this is so that in my controller I pass an array of modules to a function and it loads them in the view. I had this working by declaring the html in the helper file. I have now saved the html as a view but when trying to pass the variables from the helper to the view Im getting undefined variable errors.

My Helper:

```
if (!function_exists('twitter_feed'))
{
function twitter_feed( $user = False, $count = 3 )
{
    $ci=& get_instance();
    $ci->load->database();
    if ( $user === FALSE ) {
        $query = $ci->db->limit($count)->order_by( 'DATETIME_STAMP', 'DESC' )->get( 'twitter_feed' );
        $data['result'] = $query->result_array();
    } else {
        $query = $ci->db->limit($count)->order_by( 'DATETIME_STAMP', 'DESC' )->get_where( 'twitter_feed', array( 'SCREEN_NAME' => $user ) );
        $data['result'] = $query->result_array();
    }
    $feed = $ci->load->view('modules/twitter_feed', $data['result'], true);

    return $feed;
}   
}
```

My View

```
<section class="sponsor-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">                     
                <div class="sponsor " >                 
                    <h2 class="heading"><strong>Avid Carper's</strong> Tweets</h2>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($result as $tweet) { ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                        <div class="tweet">
                        <img src="<?=$tweet['PROFILE_IMAGE']?>" alt=""/>
                        <p><strong><?=$tweet['DISPLAY_NAME']?></strong> <br><a href="https://twitter.com/<?=$tweet['SCREEN_NAME']?>/status/<?=$tweet['TWEET_ID']?>" target="_blank"><?=$tweet['DATETIME_STAMP']?></a><br>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/<?=$tweet['SCREEN_NAME']?>" target="_blank"><span class="tw-user">@<?=$tweet['SCREEN_NAME']?></span></a>
                        <p class="tweet1"><?=$tweet['TWEET']?></p>
                        <p><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=<?=$tweet['TWEET_ID']?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Tweet this</a></p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

If I use get_defined_vars() I can see the information is there but the only way I can see of accessing them is by using $_ci_data['_ci_vars'] as I do in the following view.

```
<section class="sponsor-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">                     
                <div class="sponsor " >                 
                    <h2 class="heading"><strong>Avid Carper's</strong> Tweets</h2>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($_ci_data['_ci_vars'] as $tweet) { ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                        <div class="tweet">
                        <img src="<?=$tweet['PROFILE_IMAGE']?>" alt=""/>
                        <p><strong><?=$tweet['DISPLAY_NAME']?></strong> <br><a href="https://twitter.com/<?=$tweet['SCREEN_NAME']?>/status/<?=$tweet['TWEET_ID']?>" target="_blank"><?=$tweet['DATETIME_STAMP']?></a><br>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/<?=$tweet['SCREEN_NAME']?>" target="_blank"><span class="tw-user">@<?=$tweet['SCREEN_NAME']?></span></a>
                        <p class="tweet1"><?=$tweet['TWEET']?></p>
                        <p><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=<?=$tweet['TWEET_ID']?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Tweet this</a></p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Is there a better way to do this? as said I am loading the view from the helper to unclutter my controllers as these modules are 'blocks' in the layout.

Comment: You passing variable wrong way.It should be `$feed = $ci->load->view('modules/twitter_feed', $data, true);` at your helper

Comment: thank you. I was aware of that originally and had just passed $data but when it didnt work I tried a few alternatives. I have reverted back to just $data and it now works. I must of mistyped the variable name previously. At least it was a simple fix :)